# SAP HANA: sql syntax error while executing text mining function

Tags: text, text-mining, hana

I am trying to execute the Text Mining function `TM_GET_RELEVANT_DOCUMENTS` in SQL in SAP HANA. But getting an error:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "crash": line 3 col 6 (at pos 164)

The SQL statement should be correct as I have used an example from official SAP HANA documentation. What could be the reason for this problem?

The SQL statement is:

```
select t.rank, t.total_term_count, t.score 
  from tm_get_relevant_documents (
  term 'crash'
  language 'english'
  search distinct "ta_token" 
  from "xxx"."xxx"
  return
  top 20 
  rank, term_count
) as t where t.score > 0.25 and t.total_term_count > 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the reason is because you are using SPS09 or something earlier than that.

If you have anything less than SPS10, you can't access the SQL text mining functionality.  It wasn't introduced until SPS10.  In SPS09, you can access text mining functionality by way of the SAP HANA XS API.